# Is a locked compressed zip more secure than uncompressed locked 7-zip archive?

Tags: encryption

Using 7-Zip to lock folders. If you lock it in a compressed state, is it any difference then if it's in a store state? Security wise.

Comment: No, only encryption matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, encryption is theoretically more secure with compressed data, iirc repetition can lead to weakness.

But for real security use a real encryption program like gpg/pgp (it compresses data by default before encrypting), not zip or 7zip. Encrypting a 7zip archive using gpg works well.